# Play encrypted .m3u8 stream in exoplayer Android

Tags: android, aes, exoplayer, m3u8, exoplayer2.x

I use `ExoPlayer` in my `Android` app for playing `.m3u8` video and audio streams. It works well. But now I want to add the ability to play encrypted(aes encryption on server-side) videos. For example, I obtain from backend the next parameters:

```
streamUrl: "https://some_stream.m3u8",
aes_key: "16symbols_key",
aes_iv: "16symbols_IV",
```

decrypt the stream and play it in my `ExoPlayer`. How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at this [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5362) where it is explained how to play AES-128.

Also do check that your encryption is supported https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html